# Trying to implement a CustomObjectEvent handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, kentico

I'm basically following this [guide](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/devguide/index.html?event_handlers_overview.htm) except I'm  writing the code for Objects rather than documents. Here is my code:

```
using CMS.TreeEngine;
using CMS.SettingsProvider;

[CustomObjectEvents]
public partial class CMSModuleLoader
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Attribute class that ensures the loading of custom handlers
    /// </summary>
    private class CustomObjectEventsAttribute : CMSLoaderAttribute
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Called automatically when the application starts
        /// </summary>
        public override void Init()
        {
            // Assigns custom handlers to the appropriate events
            ObjectEvents.GetContent.Execute += Category_Get_Content; //error is here

        }

        private void Category_Get_Content(object sender, DocumentEventArgs e)
        {
            // Add custom actions here
        }

    }
}
```

The line above is throwing a compile time error:

Error   1   Cannot convert method group 'Category_Get_Content' to non-delegate type 'CMS.SettingsProvider.SimpleObjectHandler'. Did you intend to invoke the method?    C:\APPLICATIONS\DEVELOPMENT\KENTICO6\WebPartDev\wwwroot\App_Code\Blank Site\SearchByCategory.cs 22  40  C:...\wwwroot\

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change `DocumentEventArgs` to `ObjectEventArgs` in the Category_Get_Content method.